# Installed react-native-image-picker, getting "TypeError: null is not an object"

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to install react-native-image-picker. My package.json includes these:

```
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
```

My implementation of this so far is relatively simple:

```
import * as ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker"

...

    const handleChoosePhoto = async () => {
        const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary({});
        console.log(result);
    }

[Later on, there's a TouchableOpacity that calls handleChoosePhoto onPress]
```

When I try this out, I get the error: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'nativeImagePicler.launchImageLibrary')` - any tips on what to try?

I'm trying this on an Expo development build. I've tried updating react-native (was on 0.70.5, now on 0.71.8) and expo (from 47 to 48). I've also done an `npx pod-install` after installing react-native-image-picker.

Oddly, when I try the expo-image-picker library instead, I get a very similar error. Do I have to recreate the development build, since I installed a new RN library?

Comment: Is there a reason you arent using [expo-image-picker](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/)?

Comment: I tried that too, but also ran into a TypeError - very similar error to the above (though I think it was `undefined is not an object`).

Comment: After installing expo-image-picker, am I supposed to do `npx pod-install` or rebuild the development build or something else?

Comment: no since its an expo managed project it does all that stuff for you

Comment: For good measure, I created a separate SO question around my attempt to use expo-image-picker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76297134/installed-expo-image-picker-getting-typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object

Answer (score 1):

This is not the fullest answer, but...

1. I'm guessing part of the problem is trying to use react-native-image-picker with Expo. Instead, I should be trying expo-image-picker
2. I encountered a similar problem with expo-image-picker, but solved it by building a new development build ([link to other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76297134/installed-expo-image-picker-getting-typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object/76301154#76301154))

Comment: If you're using Expo Go then `react-native-image-picker` will not work, it does not claim that it's supported.