# Installed expo-image-picker, getting 'TypeError: undefined is not an object'

Tags: expo

(Posting this in conjunction with [Installed react-native-image-picker, getting "TypeError: null is not an object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76296732/installed-react-native-image-picker-getting-typeerror-null-is-not-an-object?noredirect=1#comment134543272_76296732) because I'm not sure if these have different root causes or not.)

I'm trying to get an image picker working in my Expo RN app. My package.json includes these:

```
"expo": "~48.0.15",
"expo-image-picker": "^14.1.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.8",
```

My implementation of this so far is relatively simple:

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
...

    const handleChoosePhoto = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1,
        });
        console.log(result);
    }

[Later on, there's a TouchableOpacity that calls handleChoosePhoto onPress]
```

This is following [Expo's documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/)

When I try this out, I get the error:

```
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ExponentImagePicker.default.launchImageLibraryAsync')
```

I'm trying this on an Expo development build. I've tried updating react-native (was on 0.70.5, now on 0.71.8) and expo (from 47 to 48). I've also done an npx pod-install after installing react-native-image-picker.

I also just modified my `metro.config.js` following [this suggested workaround](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36794#issuecomment-1500880284) because I was getting the - I believe unrelated - error pointing to `DatePickerIOS`.

Any tips on what's wrong?

Comment: Does it fail on both Android and iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and if I remember correctly all I had to do was rebuilding my app and publishing it again.

Comment: This came close! What ended up working for me was creating a new development build - the error didn't show up in the new one.

Comment: To be honest, I think I created a new dev build as well. As of my understanding, we need to rebuild dev client after installing some of the expo npm packages.